# Is there a tools to see how many writes an SD card has left?

Tags: monitoring, storage, sd-card, disk

Is there tool capable of reading meta-information from an SD Card?
Similar to what smartctl can do for normal hard drives?

Story:
I have built a router for a public network, and it store all its logging information and database onto an SD card. After a year, the SD card stopped working.
I assume it did too many writes and passed away. Now I want to replace it and build a tool that will alert me before the card dies,....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. The "limited number of writes" is not a counter built in by malicious manufacturer, it's a failure mode. Unfortunately, there is no reliable way to tell "when will this component break" other than statistical, e.g. "this model from this manufacturer usually lasts for 10^x writes".

Comment: well, I've read that the cards do wear leveling/block reallocation, so the number of broken blocks would be a good indicator, but I can't find a way to get the info out

Comment: @user271275: This is done inside the card itself and hidden from the computer - I'm not aware of a flash storage system which would expose this. You *might* get lucky with checking for decreasing write speeds (which may indicate massive block reallocations), but in my experience this only helps somewhat - I've had drives working fine right up to the point when they dropped dead.

Comment: Not an SD card, but SSD: The Intel SSD contain a Wear Out Indicator in its S.M.A.R.T. data. Flash device wear out is much more predictable than other failure modes in storage systems. Think about wear out as normal distributed whereas other failures in storage systems are exponential distributed.

Comment: Depends on SD card model. There are TDK cards which support native SMART and can give such information. https://product.tdk.com/info/en/products/flash-storage/flash-storage/tdksmart.html

Comment: @i486: Yes, such products now exist, but they're rare (and expensive).

Comment: If your card reader is supported by the software you have, you'll be able to get S.M.A.R.T data from the card. However, I don't know any card reader supported by e.g. `smartctl`.